# Закрасить текст при скролле страницы

Tags: javascript, css3, svg

Всем привет, пытался сделать прикольный эффект при скроле страницы:
есть секция с заголовком, заголовок прозрачный с обводкой, при прокрутке страницы, когда снизу появляется заголовок, примерно через 100px от нижнего края экрана по мере скролла он начинает заливаться снизу вверх, т.е. например мы остановились в половине залитого текста и он так и остался, пошли дальше, начал снова заливаться.

Так же, когда у нас расстояние от верхнего края до заголовка так же где-то 100px, то заливка уже начинает сходить сверху вниз, вот такая идея, на подобии [этого сайта](https://badassfilms.tv/), только там на сколько известно у них скролл кастомный и они все двигают транслейтами. Нужно сделать что-то похожее, но на стандартном скроле, если возможно. Картинка для наглядности. [image: Для наглядности]

моя статическая попытка посмотреть как это работает:

```css
section {
      background-color: #6da7ff;
      color: tomato;
      height: 100vh;
      text-align: center;
      position: relative;
  }

  div:first-child {
      position: absolute;
      width: 100%;
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      font-size: 100px;
      font-weight: bold;
      -webkit-text-stroke: 2px tomato;
      -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  }

  div:last-child {
      position: absolute;
      width: 100%;
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      font-size: 100px;
      font-weight: bold;
      clip: rect(0, 1500px, 800px, 0);
  }
```

```html
<section>
  <div >Заголовок</div>
  <div>Заголовок</div>
</section>
```

Как разобраться с js так и не смог понять..

Comment: добавьте код вашей попытки, иначе вопрос просто закроют, уже три голоса за закрытие

Comment: Возможно будет полезно, проблема решена [вот здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/949914/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%8E-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%8E-%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%83-clip-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B5)

Answer (score 0):

Ну вот как-то так:

```js
$(function() {
  $('.parallax').animate({
    scrollTop: $(document).height()
  }, 2000);
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    $('span').css('height', Math.round($(window).scrollTop() / 20) + '%');
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.parallax {
  background-color: #6ea7ff;
  height: 2000px;
}

.abc {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  line-height: 100vh;
  font-family: monospace;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 15vw;
}

span,
.abc[data-hover] {
  -webkit-text-stroke: 2px #f96545;
  text-stroke: 2px #f96545;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  text-fill-color: transparent;
  color: transparent;
}

span {
  content: attr(data-hover);
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 0%;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  -webkit-text-stroke: 0;
  text-stroke: 0;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: #f96545;
  text-fill-color: #f96545;
  color: #f96545;
  transition: all .1s ease;
}

.menu {
  left: 10px;
  top: 5px;
  position: fixed;
  font-family: monospace;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: left;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 5vw;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #f96545;
}

.menu:before {
  content: "";
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 0;
  color: #fff;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  content: attr(data-text);
  transition: all 1s;
}

.menu:hover:before {
  width: 100%;
}

.menu:after {
  content: "\2190\00A0Наведи";
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
  margin-left: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-transform: none;
  font-size: 2vw;
  line-height: 6vw;
}

.nav:before {
  content: "\2193\00A0Крути вниз";
  top: 10px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  color: #fff;
  position: fixed;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-transform: none;
  font-size: 3vw;
}

.ok {
  background-color: #f96545;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 3vw;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 2;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parallax">
  <div class="abc" data-hover="Заголовок"><span class="span">Заголовок</span>Заголовок</div>
  <div class="nav">
    <div class="menu" data-text="Меню">Меню</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="ok">Супер!</div>
```

Comment: На мобилке тухленько работает...

Comment: если в портретном расположении смарт то закрашивания нет,

Comment: https://codepen.io/krayswork/pen/wOBNzO