# Как улучшить мою версию анимации и сделать работу clip медленнее?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как улучшить мой код.

Я пробую повторить необычную анимацию "закраски" текста при прокручивании страницы. Пример сайта: [badassfilms.tv](https://badassfilms.tv/)

Мне требуется замедлить `clip`, чтобы он медленнее работал, но не при помощи `transition`. Я добавил костыль по расчету расстояния, но уверен, что есть способы намного эффективнее моего. Также хотелось бы, чтобы `clip` работал на расстояниях по ***25%*** снизу и сверху..

Пример написанного мною кода:

тут почему-то не работает код, но есть [рабочий пример тут.](https://codepen.io/krayswork/pen/wOBNzO)

```js
let windowHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight,
  windowWidth = $(window).width(),
  topDistance = windowHeight / 100 * 12,
  bottomDistance = windowHeight / 100 * 70,
  nav1 = document.querySelectorAll('.nav__1');

document.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
  for (let i = 0; i < nav1.length; i++) {
    getClip(nav1[i]);
  }
});

function getClip(element) {

  let coords = element.getBoundingClientRect();

  if (coords.y <= topDistance) { //когда заголовок за верхней "границей"
    element.style.color = '#3F3E3E';
    element.style.clip = 'rect( 0px, ' + windowWidth + 'px, 0px , 0 )';
  } else if (coords.y > topDistance && coords.y < bottomDistance) { //когда заголовок в середине экрана
    element.style.clip = 'rect( ' + ((170 - coords.y)) + 'px, ' + windowWidth + 'px, ' + windowHeight + 'px , 0 )';
  } else { // и когда заголовок пересекает нижнюю "границу"
    element.style.clip = 'rect( 0px, ' + windowWidth + 'px, ' + ((bottomDistance + 130) - coords.y) + 'px , 0 )';
  }
}
```

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: "Gilroy";
  src: url("/assets/fonts/Gilroy-Bold.eot");
  src: url("/assets/fonts/Gilroy-Bold.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"), url("/assets/fonts/Gilroy-Bold.woff2") format("woff2"), url("/assets/fonts/Gilroy-Bold.woff") format("woff"), url("/assets/fonts/Gilroy-Bold.ttf") format("truetype"), url("/assets/fonts/Gilroy-Bold.svg#Gilroy-Bold") format("svg");
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: normal;
}

section {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background-color: #b4e7ff;
  border: 1px solid tomato;
}

.nav {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  font-size: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: "Gilroy", sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  min-height: 70px;
}

.nav__1 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  color: #3F3E3E;
}

.nav__2 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-text-stroke: 2px #3F3E3E;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main-scroller">
  <section>
    <div class="nav">
      <div class="nav__1">
        Заголовок 1
      </div>
      <!-- /.nav__1 -->
      <div class="nav__2">
        Заголовок 1
      </div>
      <!-- /.nav__2 -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.nav -->
  </section>
  <section>
    <div class="nav">
      <div class="nav__1">
        Заголовок 2
      </div>
      <!-- /.nav__1 -->
      <div class="nav__2">
        Заголовок 2
      </div>
      <!-- /.nav__2 -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.nav -->
  </section>
  <section>
    <div class="nav">
      <div class="nav__1">
        Заголовок 3
      </div>
      <!-- /.nav__1 -->
      <div class="nav__2">
        Заголовок 3
      </div>
      <!-- /.nav__2 -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.nav -->
  </section>
  <section>
    <div class="nav">
      <div class="nav__1">
        Заголовок 4
      </div>
      <!-- /.nav__1 -->
      <div class="nav__2">
        Заголовок 4
      </div>
      <!-- /.nav__2 -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.nav -->
  </section>
  <section>
    <div class="nav">
      <div class="nav__1">
        Заголовок 5
      </div>
      <!-- /.nav__1 -->
      <div class="nav__2">
        Заголовок 5
      </div>
      <!-- /.nav__2 -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.nav -->
  </section>
</div>
<!-- /.main-scroller -->
```

Comment: В сафари на телефоне не работает совсем

Comment: А по существу проблемы есть что-нить?)

Comment: Сложно сказать, если не посмотреть на то, что вы хотите сделать, а я не могу =)

Comment: а хром не вариант? просто я не умею рисовать шрифты, а найти аутлайновый кирилический шрифт я не смог..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вопрос со скоростью клипа отпал, поэтому оставалось только решить проблему с расчетом расстояний. Для меня сработало следующее:

```
document.addEventListener('scroll', function () {

    for (let i = 0; i < nav1.length; i++) {
        elemHeight = nav1[i].offsetHeight;
        getClip(nav1[i], elemHeight);

    }
});


function getClip (element, height) {

    let coords = element.getBoundingClientRect();

    if (coords.y <= topDistance){ //когда заголовок за верхней "границей"

        element.style.color = '#3F3E3E';
        element.style.clip = 'rect( 0px, '+ windowWidth+'px, 0px , 0 )';

    } else  if (coords.y > topDistance && coords.y < bottomDistance){ //когда заголовок в середине экрана

        element.style.clip = 'rect( '+((topDistance+height)-coords.y)+'px, '+ windowWidth+'px, '+ windowHeight +'px , 0 )';

    } else { // и когда заголовок пересекает нижнюю "границу"

        element.style.clip = 'rect( 0px, '+ windowWidth+'px, '+ ((bottomDistance+height)-coords.y) +'px , 0 )';

    }
}
```

То есть я вычисляю высоту каждого элемента, прибавляю её к расстоянию либо снизу экрана, либо сверху и из этого числа отнимаю координаты, на которых сейчас находится элемент.

Посмотреть как это работает можно по прежнему [Здесь](https://codepen.io/krayswork/pen/wOBNzO)

Заранее: это не работает в браузерах, не поддерживающих -webkit-text-stroke и -webkit-text-fill-color